# Firefox and Discord misbehaving after upgrading 21.10 to 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, kde, snap, 22.04

Both Firefox and Discord, which appear to be snaps now but I don't think they started as snaps, give me notifications in the corner (Kubuntu, so KDE) that I need to "Close the app to avoid disruptions" for a pending update.  I've closed both apps multiple times now, and I've run all of my updates from Discover in between doing so, but these popups keep coming up.  The Firefox one says 10 days left, but...I don't know what it's counting down those 10 days for.  Is that when I get disrupted?  And if so, why?

Firefox has an additional problem where it asks me if I want to set it to be my default web browser every time I open it.  I always click yes, and I always check the box to not ask me again.  But then it asks me again.

Any idea how to resolve these two issues?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to dismiss the "Close app to avoid disruption" notification, but I haven't seen it for a few days. Maybe you can try updating all snaps by running the `sudo snap refresh` command.

To remove the popup asking to set Firefox as your default browser, you can go to Firefox's Settings, and untick the box labeled *Always check if Firefox is your default browser*. It will probably say that Firefox still isn't the default browser, but you can just ignore that.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the refresh appeared to work.  Discord prompted me with the new version changes, and there was a visible progress bar for the firefox update.  Is there a GUI element somewhere that is supposed to handle the updating of snaps like that refresh command just did?  Also, I can uncheck the "Always check if Firefox is your default browser" box, but it will not recognize itself as my default browser, even after hitting the "Make Default" button on this same page.

Comment: @user4776 I think snaps are supposed to update automatically in the background when unused. For my part, I couldn't find a GUI. AIso, I have the same issue with Firefox not recognizing itself as the default browser and unfortunately, I don't know how to fix it :(

Comment: Update in the background when unused?  But I'm basically ALWAYS running these two programs, haha.  That makes the snap versions essentially useless to me.  I guess I'll just replace them.